# meaning of phrase "continuing their friend"

Tags: meaning, phrases

In the following passage, the meaning obviously is "continuing to be their friend", but I wonder if this is merely a poetic elliptical construction or there is actually a grammatical explanation.

> I have persevered in helping people all I could and continuing their friend.

Also, is my understanding correct of the meaning as “continuing *to be* their friend”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does mean *continuing to be.* I would say the usage was a little old-fashioned, but it's perfectly grammatical. See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/continue , definition 1.2.

Comment: It doesn't sound grammatical to me.  Either "and continue being their friend" or "and continuing their friendship" sounds much better.

Comment: @ib11 - I never said the definition was wrong, just its grammaticality. The example has a preposition (*in*) which differs from OP's usage.

Comment: @Jim Thanks. But I do think this is irrelevant, since it is not something I am writing but something I was reading. So I believe we can just delete all these comments as they do not add to the answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Not a phrase I have ever come across myself, I would call it bad English rather than poetry, but perhaps you can give more context, where the quote is from?

Comment: This is a comment - not an answer.